# Change contents of NSTextField depending on selected item of NSTableView using the same Array Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a `Core Data Entity` named `Toys` with two `attributes`: an `integer` named `identifier` and an `NSString` named `details`.

My storyboard setup consists of a split view with an `NSTableView` on the left and an `NSTextField` on the right. The table on the left is displaying a list of the existing toy objects with their identifier integers, and I'd like to change the content of the text field on the right so it corresponds to the details of the object selected on the table.

I'm trying to achieve that by using `Cocoa Bindings`. To set up the table, I created an `Array Controller` connected to the `Toys` entity. To hook up the `NSTextField`, I bound the `value` of the field to that same array controller.

Currently, the table will gather a list of all my objects but the text field will load the description for a random object of the array each time I run the application. How could I change the contents of the text field based on the row selected on the left side? I'd prefer to use bindings if available.

[image: example]

Comment: To which Controller Key did you bind the text field? Did you bind Selection Indexes of the table view?

Comment: You need to ensure the table's selection is also bound to the AC, not just the content.  You then bind the text field to the AC's selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I was indeed missing a connection from the table to the array controller. Fixed by binding the `table` to the `array controller` under `Selection Indexes`, with `selectionIndexes` set as `Controller Key`.